# JVM Perm Gen / System freeze after capturing a function which is generated in an interpreter run

Tags: scala, jvm, classloader, interpreter

I am using Scala dynamically embedded, and I thought I was smart to save re-interpretation of bits by capturing them in a `Function0` of the host program. Approximately like this:

```
object Code
  def intp: IMain = ???

  object Capture {
    private val vr = new ThreadLocal[() => Any]

    def apply[A](thunk: => A) {
      vr.set(() => thunk)
    }

    def result: () => Any = vr.get()
  }

  def capture(code: String): Future[() => Any] = future {
    blocking {
      intp.setExecutionWrapper("Code.Capture")
      intp.interpret(code)
      Capture.result
    }
  }
}
```

This "somehow" works, but soon after the JVM goes nuts, basically hangs, produces Perm Gen errors etc. So I must be doing something forbidden. If I do not use the capture mechanism, it all runs smoothly (but I have to re-execute the `interpret` method over and over again instead of keeping the compiled function), so there is nothing wrong on that end.

I tried to run through a step debugger to see if I find anything suspicious, but no. At some point the program just completely freezes. I also isolated the futures case by launching a separate thread for the compilation with an auxiliary `Promise` on the main `capture` block that waits for is completion, that didn't change anything.

Any help is appreciated. Perhaps there is a confusion with class loaders and such? (my `IMain` does override `parentClassLoader` to be able to access the host classes).

---

I had a final intuition that perhaps I should serialize the function in the `apply` method (`writeObject`), and then deserialise in the host. But the `readObject` then produces a

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $line1.$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1
```

Hinting perhaps at the problem beneath?